How do I resolve the error Could not resolve all files for configuration :core:debugCompileClasspath
     I Get the error 
     
     Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':core:debugCompileClasspath'.
     
     Build files
     
     Build.gradle (Project: Micro)
     
        // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
     buildscript {
         ext {
             kotlin_version = '1.7.20'
             lifecycleVersion = "2.5.1"
             exoplayerVersion = "2.18.1"
             daggerVersion = "2.44"
             room_version = "2.4.3"
             okhttpVersion = "4.10.0"
             coroutinesVersion = "1.6.4"
             workVersion = "2.7.1"
             materialVersion = "1.7.0"
             jodaVersion = "2.10.6"
             appcompatVersion = "1.5.1"
         }
     
         apply from: 'versions.gradle'
         repositories {
             google()
             mavenCentral()
         }
         dependencies {
             classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1'
             classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
             classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.14'
             classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.9.2'
             classpath 'com.google.firebase:perf-plugin:1.4.2'
             classpath "com.squareup:javapoet:1.13.0"
         }
     }
     
     allprojects {
         repositories {
             google()
             mavenCentral()
             maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
             maven {url 'https://repo.clojars.org/'}
     
         }
     }
     
     task clean(type: Delete) {
         delete rootProject.buildDir
     }
     
     Version.gradle (Project: Micro)
     ext.deps = [:]
     def versions = [:]
     versions.activity = '1.1.0'
     versions.annotations = "1.0.0"
     versions.apache_commons = "2.5"
     versions.arch_core = "2.1.0"
     versions.atsl_core = "1.2.0"
     versions.atsl_junit = "1.2.1"
     versions.atsl_rules = "1.2.0"
     versions.atsl_runner = "1.2.0"
     versions.benchmark = "1.1.0-alpha01"
     versions.cardview = "1.0.0"
     versions.constraint_layout = "2.0.4"
     versions.dexmaker = "2.2.0"
     versions.espresso = "3.2.0"
     versions.fragment = "1.2.1"
     versions.glide = "4.11.0"
     versions.hamcrest = "1.3"
     versions.junit = "4.13"
     versions.material = "1.3.0-alpha01"
     versions.mockito = "2.25.0"
     versions.mockito_all = "1.10.19"
     versions.mockito_android = "2.25.0"
     versions.mockwebserver = "3.8.1"
     versions.navigation = "2.3.0-alpha01"
     versions.paging = "3.0.0-alpha01"
     versions.recyclerview = "1.2.0-alpha04"
     versions.retrofit = "2.9.0"
     versions.robolectric = "4.2"
     versions.rx_android = "2.0.1"
     versions.timber = "4.7.1"
     versions.transition = "1.3.0"
     versions.truth = "1.0.1"
     versions.ted_permission = "2.2.2"
     ext.versions = versions
     
     def build_versions = [:]
     build_versions.min_sdk = 21
     build_versions.compile_sdk = 33
     build_versions.target_sdk = 33
     build_versions.build_tools = "33.0.0"
     ext.build_versions = build_versions
     
     def deps = [:]
     
     def activity = [:]
     activity.activity_ktx = "androidx.activity:activity-ktx:$versions.activity"
     deps.activity = activity
     
     deps.annotations = "androidx.annotation:annotation:$versions.annotations"
     
     def atsl = [:]
     atsl.core = "androidx.test:core:$versions.atsl_core"
     atsl.ext_junit = "androidx.test.ext:junit:$versions.atsl_junit"
     atsl.runner = "androidx.test:runner:$versions.atsl_runner"
     atsl.rules = "androidx.test:rules:$versions.atsl_rules"
     deps.atsl = atsl
     
     deps.benchmark = "androidx.benchmark:benchmark-junit4:$versions.benchmark"
     deps.benchmark_gradle = "androidx.benchmark:benchmark-gradle-plugin:$versions.benchmark"
     deps.cardview = "androidx.cardview:cardview:$versions.cardview"
     deps.constraint_layout = "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:$versions.constraint_layout"
     deps.core_ktx = "androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0"
     
     deps.dexmaker = "com.linkedin.dexmaker:dexmaker-mockito:$versions.dexmaker"
     
     def espresso = [:]
     espresso.core = "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0"
     espresso.contrib = "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:3.4.0"
     espresso.intents = "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-intents:3.4.0"
     deps.espresso = espresso
     
     def fragment = [:]
     fragment.runtime = "androidx.fragment:fragment:${versions.fragment}"
     fragment.runtime_ktx = "androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:${versions.fragment}"
     fragment.testing = "androidx.fragment:fragment-testing:${versions.fragment}"
     deps.fragment = fragment
     
     def glide = [:]
     glide.runtime = "com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:$versions.glide"
     glide.compiler = "com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:$versions.glide"
     glide.annotations = "com.github.bumptech.glide:annotations:$versions.glide"
     glide.okhttp = "com.github.bumptech.glide:okhttp3-integration:$versions.glide"
     deps.glide = glide
     
     deps.hamcrest = "org.hamcrest:hamcrest-all:$versions.hamcrest"
     
     deps.junit = "junit:junit:$versions.junit"
     
     deps.material = "com.google.android.material:material:$versions.material"
     
     def mockito = [:]
     mockito.core = "org.mockito:mockito-core:$versions.mockito"
     mockito.all = "org.mockito:mockito-all:$versions.mockito_all"
     mockito.android = "org.mockito:mockito-android:$versions.mockito_android"
     deps.mockito = mockito
     
     //deps.mock_web_server = "com.squareup.okhttp3:mockwebserver:$versions.mockwebserver"
     
     def navigation = [:]
     navigation.runtime = "androidx.navigation:navigation-runtime:$versions.navigation"
     navigation.runtime_ktx = "androidx.navigation:navigation-runtime-ktx:$versions.navigation"
     navigation.fragment = "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:$versions.navigation"
     navigation.fragment_ktx = "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$versions.navigation"
     navigation.testing = "androidx.navigation:navigation-testing:$versions.navigation"
     navigation.ui = "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:$versions.navigation"
     navigation.ui_ktx = "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$versions.navigation"
     navigation.safe_args_plugin = "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:$versions.navigation"
     deps.navigation = navigation
     
     deps.paging_runtime = "androidx.paging:paging-runtime:$versions.paging"
     deps.recyclerview = "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:$versions.recyclerview"
     
     def retrofit = [:]
     retrofit.runtime = "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$versions.retrofit"
     retrofit.gson = "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:$versions.retrofit"
     retrofit.mock = "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit-mock:$versions.retrofit"
     //retrofit.adapter = "com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:$versions.retrofit"
     deps.retrofit = retrofit
     
     deps.robolectric = "org.robolectric:robolectric:$versions.robolectric"
     deps.ted_permission = "gun0912.ted:tedpermission:$versions.ted_permission"
     deps.timber = "com.jakewharton.timber:timber:$versions.timber"
     deps.transition = "androidx.transition:transition:$versions.transition"
     deps.truth = "com.google.truth:truth:$versions.truth"
     
     ext.deps = deps
     
     def addRepos(RepositoryHandler handler) {
         handler.google()
         handler.jcenter()
         handler.maven { url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots' }
     
     }
     ext.addRepos = this.&addRepos
     
     Build.gradle( Module :app)
     plugins {
         id 'com.android.application'
         id 'kotlin-android'
         id 'kotlin-parcelize'
         id 'kotlin-kapt'
         id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
         id 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
         id 'com.google.firebase.firebase-perf'
     }
     
     android {
         compileSdkVersion build_versions.compile_sdk
         buildToolsVersion build_versions.build_tools
     
         defaultConfig {
             applicationId "com.qbicles.micro"
             minSdkVersion build_versions.min_sdk
             targetSdkVersion build_versions.target_sdk
             versionCode 4
             versionName "1.0"
     
             testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
     
             buildConfigField "String", "AWS_CONFIG", '"Default"'
         }
     
         buildFeatures{
     //        dataBinding = true
             // for view binding :
              viewBinding = true
         }
     
         buildTypes {
             debug {
                 versionNameSuffix = "_d"
                 minifyEnabled false
             }
     
             release {
                 minifyEnabled false
                 proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
     
                 buildConfigField "String", "AWS_CONFIG", '"Live"'
             }
         }
         compileOptions {
             sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
             targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
         }
         kotlinOptions {
             jvmTarget = '1.8'
             freeCompilerArgs += [
                     "-Xuse-experimental=kotlinx.coroutines.ExperimentalCoroutinesApi",
                     "-Xuse-experimental=kotlinx.coroutines.ObsoleteCoroutinesApi"]
         }
     
         lintOptions {
             abortOnError false
         }
     }
     
     dependencies {
         implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
         implementation project(path: ':core')
         implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.6'
         implementation 'com.intuit.ssp:ssp-android:1.0.6'
         implementation 'com.google.guava:listenablefuture:9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava'
         // Core Kotlin
         implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
     
         // Appcompat AndroidX
         implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:$appcompatVersion"
     
         // Kotlin Extension
         implementation deps.core_ktx
         implementation 'com.google.android.play:core-ktx:1.8.1'
         implementation deps.activity.activity_ktx
         implementation deps.fragment.runtime_ktx
         implementation deps.constraint_layout
     
         // Dagger
         implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:$daggerVersion"
         kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$daggerVersion"
         implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger-android:$daggerVersion"
         implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:$daggerVersion" // if you use the support libraries
         kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:$daggerVersion"
     
         implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
         implementation project(path: ':signalr-client-sdk-android')
         implementation project(path: ':signalr-client-sdk')
         implementation "com.google.android.material:material:$materialVersion"
     
     
         // Glide
         implementation deps.glide.runtime
         implementation deps.glide.annotations
         implementation deps.glide.okhttp
         kapt deps.glide.compiler
     
     
         // Network
         implementation deps.retrofit.runtime
         implementation deps.retrofit.gson
         implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:$okhttpVersion"
     
         // Coroutines
         implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:$coroutinesVersion"
         implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:$coroutinesVersion"
     
         implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:$lifecycleVersion"
         implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:$lifecycleVersion"
         implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:$lifecycleVersion"
         implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-savedstate:$lifecycleVersion"
     
         //Circle Image border
         implementation 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.3.0'
     
         // Joda Time
         implementation "joda-time:joda-time:$jodaVersion"
     
         // BEGIN AWS DEPENDENCIES
         implementation ('com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-mobile-client:2.16.13@aar') { transitive = true }
         implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-s3:2.16.13'
         implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-cognito:2.16.13'
         // END AWS DEPENDENCIES
     
         // SignalR
         //implementation 'com.microsoft.signalr:signalr:1.0.0'
     
         implementation 'com.github.dewinjm:monthyear-picker:1.0.2'
     
         //Firebase
         implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:31.0.1')
         implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx'
         implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-ktx'
         implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf'
     
         // DateTime picker
         implementation 'com.github.Kunzisoft:Android-SwitchDateTimePicker:2.0'
     
         implementation 'com.hyman:flowlayout-lib:1.1.2'
     
         implementation "com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-core:$exoplayerVersion"
         implementation "com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-dash:$exoplayerVersion"
         implementation "com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-ui:$exoplayerVersion"
         implementation "com.google.android.exoplayer:extension-okhttp:$exoplayerVersion"
         implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:21.0.0'
         implementation group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: '2.8.0'
     //    implementation "com.andkulikov:transitionseverywhere:1.8.1"
     
         implementation 'com.ToxicBakery.viewpager.transforms:view-pager-transforms:1.3.7'
         implementation 'com.github.smarteist:autoimageslider:1.4.0-appcompat'
         implementation("androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.1.0")
         implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0'
         implementation 'com.github.warkiz.widget:indicatorseekbar:2.1.2'
         implementation 'com.github.dhaval2404:imagepicker-support:1.7.1'
         implementation 'pub.devrel:easypermissions:3.0.0'
     
         // Room components
         implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
         implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:$room_version"
         kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
     //    implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:$rootProject.roomVersion"
     //    kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$rootProject.roomVersion"
     //    androidTestImplementation "androidx.room:room-testing:$rootProject.roomVersion"
         //implementation 'co.paystack.android:paystack:3.1.3'
         implementation project(path: ':paystack')
         implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:21.0.0'
     
         def chuckerVersion = '3.5.2'
         debugImplementation "com.github.chuckerteam.chucker:library:$chuckerVersion"
         releaseImplementation "com.github.chuckerteam.chucker:library-no-op:$chuckerVersion"
     
         implementation 'com.github.konifar:creditcard-input-helper:0.4.2'
         implementation 'com.splitwise:tokenautocomplete:3.0.1@aar'
     
         implementation("com.tbuonomo:dotsindicator:4.3")
     
         implementation 'com.google.android.flexbox:flexbox:3.0.0'
     
     }
     
     Build.gradle(Module:core)
     apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
     apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
     apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
     apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
     
     android {
         compileSdkVersion build_versions.compile_sdk
         buildToolsVersion build_versions.build_tools
     
         defaultConfig {
             minSdkVersion build_versions.min_sdk
             targetSdkVersion build_versions.target_sdk
     
             testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
     
             buildConfigField "String", "BASE_AUTH_URL", '"https://dev1-auth.qbicles.com/"'
             buildConfigField "String", "BASE_ACCOUNT_URL", '"https://dev1-web.qbicles.com/"'
             buildConfigField "String", "BASE_URL", '"https://dev1-micro.qbicles.com/api/"'
             buildConfigField "String", "BASE_SIGNAL_URL", '"https://dev1-coms.qbicles.com"'
             buildConfigField "String", "BASE_DOCUMENT_URL", '"https://dev1-doc.qbicles.com/"'
         }
     
         buildFeatures{
             dataBinding = true
             // for view binding :
             // viewBinding = true
         }
     
         buildTypes {
             release {
                 minifyEnabled false
                 proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
     
                 buildConfigField "String", "BASE_AUTH_URL", '"https://auth-h.qbicles.com/"'
                 buildConfigField "String", "BASE_ACCOUNT_URL", '"https://home.qbicles.com/"'
                 buildConfigField "String", "BASE_URL", '"https://micro.qbicles.com/api/"'
                 buildConfigField "String", "BASE_SIGNAL_URL", '"https://coms.qbicles.com"'
                 buildConfigField "String", "BASE_DOCUMENT_URL", '"https://doc.qbicles.com/"'
             }
         }
     
         compileOptions {
             sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
             targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
         }
         kotlinOptions {
             jvmTarget = "1.8"
         }
     }
     
     dependencies {
     //    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
     
     //    implementation deps.kotlin.stdlib
     //    implementation "androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:$workVersion"
         implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:$appcompatVersion"
     
         // Dagger
         implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:$daggerVersion"
         annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$daggerVersion"
         implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger-android:$daggerVersion"
         implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:$daggerVersion" // if you use the support libraries
         annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:$daggerVersion"
     
         implementation deps.recyclerview
     
         // Material
         implementation "com.google.android.material:material:$materialVersion"
         implementation deps.constraint_layout
     
         implementation deps.retrofit.runtime
         implementation deps.retrofit.gson
         implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:$okhttpVersion"
     
         implementation deps.core_ktx
     
         implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:$coroutinesVersion"
         implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:$coroutinesVersion"
     
         implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:$lifecycleVersion"
         implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:$lifecycleVersion"
         implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:$lifecycleVersion"
     
         implementation deps.fragment.runtime_ktx
     
         implementation 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.3.0'
     
         implementation deps.glide.runtime
         implementation deps.glide.okhttp
         kapt deps.glide.compiler
     
         implementation deps.ted_permission
     
         testImplementation deps.junit
         androidTestImplementation deps.atsl.ext_junit
         androidTestImplementation deps.espresso.core
     
         debugImplementation 'com.readystatesoftware.chuck:library:1.1.0'
         releaseImplementation 'com.readystatesoftware.chuck:library-no-op:1.1.0'
     
         //customview
         implementation 'jp.wasabeef:glide-transformations:4.0.0'
         implementation "joda-time:joda-time:$jodaVersion"
     
         implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:31.0.1')
         implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database'
     
         implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.6'
         implementation 'com.intuit.ssp:ssp-android:1.0.6'
     //    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
     
         implementation 'pub.devrel:easypermissions:3.0.0'
     }
     repositories {
         mavenCentral()
     }
     

I keep on getting the issue below
Caused by:        org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':core:debugCompileClasspath'.
Please is there a solution that can be used to resolve this issue
I tried changing the configurations and going through various answers on stack overflow but nothing worked. I have now updated the question.

It would help if you supplied the complete error message and the complete build file.

Sorry for the late response.
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':core:debugCompileClasspath'.
That is the error message.
